Kartik Tree Manager and file upload
I'd like to allow the user to upload a file in addition to creating a node, but unfortunately, I can't get it to work.
I added the view below inside the nodaddlViews which contains:
echo $form
    ->field($node,'f_content')
    ->fileInput()
    ->label('Select File');

It correctly displays and functions, but when I save the file, its content inside the database is always the same as "0x".
I also tried putting this in the controller's save function, but I don't think it's being executed as code:
...

public function actionCreate($parent_id = null)
{
    $model = new Folders();

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        if ($parent_id !== null) {
            $parent = Folders::findOne($parent_id);
            if ($parent) {
                $model->prependTo($parent);
            }
        }
        $h=(binary)(file_get_contents($model->f_content));
        $model->setAttribute('f_content', $h);
        if ($model->save()) {
            Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success', 'The record has been saved successfully.');
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        } else {
            Yii::$app->session->setFlash('error', 'An error occurred while saving.');
        }
    }

    return $this->render(
        'create', [
        'model' => $model,
        ]
    );
}
...


you are missing the UploadFile instance. Check the wiring up part: https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/input-file-upload#wiring-up

hi thadude!
also using this UploadFile fail, i have seen tha the tree on save dont call module->Create but treeview->node->Save, i have solved using a popup form to save file, but i think that if i want to use it in native mode i have to work on source...

Show what you tried and maybe add your solution. Did you add the f_content attribute to your tree class and mark it save? Yii´s save function knows if its creating or updating data, by checking for existing _oldAttributes.
